# Assign value to global module variable with javascript from another function

Tags: javascript, module, global

I often create modules like this in javascript.

```
var myModule = (function () {
    var fn = {};
    var test = 'Global module data';

    fn.init = function(field, a_test) {
        test = a_test;
    };

    return fn;
})();
```

I add the variable `test` in the module scope. From the outside I send `a_test` to this module. Later I set this value to `test`. While it works fine, it feels weird to do that.

Of obvious reasons, this does not work.

```
fn.init = function(field, test) {
    test = test;
};
```

What is the correct approach to make `a_test` find its way to the module scope.

Comment: What exactly feels weird about it, is it only about the variable name (`a_test`) that you tried to rename?

Comment: `test` is not in the global scope, it's in the local scope of the module IIFE. If you just had a global variable, you wouldn't need `init` at all.

Comment: @Bergi I would prefer to not needing to rename it in order to get it to the module scope.

Comment: That's impossible, the `init` parameter and the module data are two different variables and need different names to use them both in an assignment. Of course, the solution is not to use such an `init` method at all, but which proper design to choose depends on a few factors: what does the module do, what is the test data, why is the setup of the data external, who calls the `init` method, when is the `init` method called, how often is the `init` method called?